# PHP Converting string to a select form box

Tags: php, string, drop-down-menu

I have some values returned as a string from another application.

They are in this format:

```
key1|value1,key2|value2,key3|value3
```

I'm trying to manipulate that so I can get it in this format:

```
<select>
<option value="key1">value1</option>
<option value="key2">value2</option>
<option value="key3">value3</option>
</select>
```

So each list item is separated by a comma, but then each list key and value pair are separated by a |

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

There can be an unknown number of items per list. I just used three as an example.

Comment: Well, you explode the string into separate items, then output the `select` bracket and inside you iterate over the items to output them. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primitive, but should do the job:

```
<?php
$input = 'key1|value1,key2|value2,key3|value3';
$rawItems = explode(',', $input);
echo "<select>\n";
foreach ($rawItems as $rawItem) {
  list($key, $val) = explode('|', $rawItem);
  echo sprintf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>\n", htmlentities($key), htmlentities($val));
}
echo "</select>\n";
```

The output is:

```
<select>
<option value="key1">value1</option>
<option value="key2">value2</option>
<option value="key3">value3</option>
</select>
```

*This is for testing on CLI. For output in a browser you should replace the line breaks by `<br>` tags.*

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code :

```
$s = "key1|value1,key2|value2,key3|value3";
$e = explode(",",$s);
for($i=0;$i<count($e);$i++) {
   $newex = explode("|",$e[$i]);
   echo '<option value="'.$newex[0].'">'.$newex[1].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `str_replace`, (don't need a loop):

```
$full_string = 'key1|value1,key2|value2,key3|value3';

$options = str_replace(',', '</option><option value="', $full_string);
$options = str_replace('|', '">', $options);

echo '<select><option value="' . $options . '</option></select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mainString = "key1|value1,key2|value2,key3|value3";
$optArray   = explode(",", $mainString);
$optString  = "";
foreach($optArray as $optIndSting) {
    $expIndString = explode("|", $optIndSting);
    $optString.= '<option value="'.$expIndString[0].'">'.$expIndString[1].'</option>';
}
```

use `$optString` to your select box,

terms used.

1. `explode` expects to parameters, first the needle, second the string.
   http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp
2. `foreach` a loop statements which iterates values inside an array.
   http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp